# making a customized list view in android showing the track of a bus

Tags: android, android-layout

how can I make a layout that looks like this [image]  in android using list view.
I am making a tracking system for many buses. If the bus crossed the location the circle will turn green else it is red.
**I just want a vertical line which has length depending on the number of stops for the bus.**
*the line should be passing through the center of the circles.*
Here is the listBusStops.xml file
`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivstatus"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/tvname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            />

    </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`

here the custom_list class which I am using
`

```
class Custom_list extends ArrayAdapter {
private final Activity context;
   private final Integer imageid;
   ArrayList<String> list;
   ArrayList<String> status;
public Custom_list(Activity context, ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<String> status, Integer imageid) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_bus_stops,Track_any_bus.stop_name);

    this.context=context;
    this.list = list;
    this.imageid=imageid;
    this.status = status;
}

public View getView (int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_bus_stops,null,true);// ALL LAYOUT RESOURSE OF list_bus_stops SAVED TO THIS VIEW(rowview)
    TextView textView =  rowview.findViewById(R.id.tvname);//
    ImageView imageView = rowview.findViewById(R.id.ivstatus);
    textView.setText(Track_any_bus.stop_name.get(position));
    if(Track_any_bus.status.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_green);
    }
    else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_red);
    }
    return rowview;
}
```

`

thank you for your time.

Comment: First try to develop something and share your code, we'll help you, but this question is too broad.

Comment: Begin learning some layouts and I'm sure you'll get some ideas to face this problem. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

Comment: try to use RecyclerView with custom adapter , i think this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the demo working code plz have a look i hope it will help you**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="#D3D3D3" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
                    android:tint="#000000"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_round_solid" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="12dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#ffff"

                    >


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:background="#800000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"></LinearLayout>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/noteTitle"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Title"
                            android:background="#000000 "
                            android:textSize="20dp" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:background="#800000"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"></LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                android:textColor="#000080"
                                android:text="Text-Preview"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textPreview"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                android:textColor="#000080"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Sample Text"
                                />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                android:textColor="#000080"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:text="Last Modified"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/lastModified"
                                android:textColor="#000080"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:text="12/4/2018"
                                />
                        </LinearLayout>



                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you want i can share you the design screen shot

Comment: You can use listview in place of cardview